# Using FLVPlayback Class to play an instance of the Video class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flv, flvplayback

Is it possible to use the FLVPlayback class to play an instance of the Video class? I'm loading the video (which is just an audio track with cue points) in using GreenSocks LoaderMax (along with the rest of my assets) and so have various instances of Video. The FLVPlayback class only accepts a String as its' source. Is there any way to hack it to bypass whatever loading it does and just feed it the video directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nope, not that I know of anyway.

the Video objects need to have NetStream objects attached to them to play a video.

The FLVPlayback component generates the needed NetConnection/NetStream objects internally based on the source path supplied. A video object cannot be inspected for its NetStream object. You could use your Video objects and attach some playback control components to it if you don't want to build out a custom UI.